# Did Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem ever led to number theoretical insights?

Tags: number-theory, incompleteness

Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem is based on the construction of a formula - a so-called Gödel formula - stating its own unprovability. Has ever such a formula led to novel insights in number theory (beside arithmetics' incompleteness)?

Intuitively, a Gödel formula would be an excellent candidate as an additional axiom which, even though not making arithmetics' axiomatization complete, would most likely result in novel and interesting theorems.

To the best of my knowledge, this path has so far not been followed. Am I  right or were number theoretical results gained from exploiting a Gödel formula?

Comment: I think a more general question would be: what are examples of true statements about natural number that are not deducible from Peano Arithmetic but which have been used in number theory?  I am convinced that there are ways to find such statements without passing by Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem (for example: [Paris–Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem)).  It would be hard to imagine for me that the statement coming from Gödel's Theorem would be of special importance among such...

Comment: I do not think that Goedel's results are useful to detect additional aspects in number theory, but since Goedel we know that famous open conjectures could be unsolvable. An important example of a known unsolvable problem is to determine whether a diophantine equation has an integer solution.

Comment: @Alexey Yes, "there are ways to to find such statements without passing by Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem": Matiyasevich's theorem (or DPRM-theorem) improves over Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem in giving as unprovable statement that a particular Diophantine equation has no solution.

Comment: @Peter I also do not think that Goedel's results have been useful to detect additional aspects in number theory. This puzzles me.

Comment: I think you answered your own question by invoking the 10th problem. There is been significant insight gained from work on generalizations of the DPRM theorem.

Comment: @François Bry : that's definitely true, but in the "canonical" proof I know of the DPRM theorem (the undecidability of a particular decision problem for Diophantine equations), someone could argue that we just use computability, not incompleteness. The incompleteness aspects are not as interesting to non-logicians.

Comment: @Carl Yes, that is true. It would be great to see something more direct, I think the question has some interesting potential.

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedo: I am doubtful there are many examples, if there are any, for the reasons I sketched below.

Comment: @FrançoisBry, the statement of the DPRM theorem in Wikipedia does not seem to give any example of a true but PA-unprovable statement about natural numbers. Neither does it suggest any method to find such statements. How would you find a Diophantine equation that has no solutions but such that this fact is unprovable in PA?

Comment: @Alexey You are right: True but PA-unprovable sentences seem to be animals only to be found in Gödel's zoo.

Comment: @FrançoisBry, as i said in my first comment, i do not think so, and in fact, according to Wikipedia, "the strengthened finite Ramsey theorem" is not provable in PA (but i am not a specialist and would not know what it says without looking it up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The incompleteness theorem has led to interesting discoveries such as the unprovability of the [Paris-Harrington principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) and similar principles in Peano arithmetic.

However, it doesn't help us much to include the Gödel sentence for PA as a new axiom, because number theorists do not limit themselves to Peano Arithmetic - they are generally interested simply in proving results, not proving them in Peano Arithmetic. For example, the Paris-Harrington theorem is simple to prove in ZFC, so number theorists would typically just view it as a particular (and simple) combinatorial theorem.

Logicians have been very interested in what is provable in systems of arithmetic, but they  rarely develop genuinely "new" theorems of number theory while doing so. Part of this is because they are generally interested in theorems that are both independent of PA (for example) and also provable in general - but once a result is provable in general, non-logicians are less interested in whether it is provable in PA.

One way that we could try to prove genuinely *new* number theory results would be to add axioms to ZFC, rather than PA. That might increase the number of results that I am calling provable "in general".

When people do talk about adding additional axioms beyond ZFC, they typically include axioms that *imply* Gödel-type sentences, but are much stronger than Gödel sentences themselves. Many of these additional axioms are "large cardinal" axioms in set theory. But even these don't seem to have much practical effect on everyday number theory, etc., although they do let us prove additional statements of a more set-theoretic flavor.

Comment: However, adding axioms to ZFC directly is quite a different affair from adding axioms to PA. What properties should the additional axioms satisfy? It does not make sense to say if the axioms of ZFC are "true" or "false," and i would not even "bet my life" on ZF's being consistent. On the other hand, the axioms of PA can be viewed as statements about the ordinary natural numbers, and i believe that the majority of mathematicians know that they are true (exceptions [exist](https://mathoverflow.net/q/40920)). One can look for new true statements about natural numbers not deducible from PA.

Comment: In fact, the starting point should anyway be at least second-order arithmetic, not PA...